# Date and time conversion from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a query where I fetch date with a sql query. And wondering how to use the CONVERT function to not show todays date, but convert the date saved in the database which is named as: routines.date. The goal is to sort it as D-M-Y and now its saved as Y-M-D

This didn't work:

```
CONVERT(date,routines.date,105) as Date
```

Comment: In the t-Sql documentation I don't see that GetDate() takes a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(routines.date AS DATETIME), 105)
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy, @routines.date)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(mm, @routines.date)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd, @routines.date))
```